# How to secure 3rd party API keys with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

Our products are deployed on `AWS`.
We use a few 3rd party services like `Sendgrid` and `Twillio`.

I know in `Heroku` I can easily set my `API KEYS` in the dashboard and then access my **NODEJS** project like this

```
process.env.SENDGRID_KEY
```

How do I achieve the same in `AWS`?
Where can I put my keys and refer to that?

Comment: What kind of compute do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) is used on AWS to store sensitive data such as API keys. You can store your secrets using the console and use the AWS SDK to fetch the values in your applications.

For NodeJs, you can either use [Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SSM.html) or [aws-param-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-param-store) module to manage parameters.

Remember to attach required [IAM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html) to the application host (EC2 instance/lambda).